# Is it possible to store all the application's data in sdcard?

Tags: android

We need to create our own file structure on sdcard for storing preference files,database files and files ?

Is this possible ? I know we can store files anywhere on sdcard but not sure about SQLiteDatabase files and Shared Preference files .

Please provide me suggestions on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ya its possible while developing an application.in manifest just give

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

then the application and the file of the application will be dierectly written to the external storage of the device that is to the SD card.You will be having two more options "auto" and "intenalOnly" just like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="*******************"
package="*************"
android:versionCode="1"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Can we create files,preferences ,databases on the sdcard folder1/folder2/files/,folder1/folder2/preferences/,folder1/folder2/databases/     ?  is this possible ?

Comment: ya its possible,you can give path via code,but its not a good scenario to follow.

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE) returns E/AndroidRuntime(530): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /mnt/sdcard/folder1/folder2/000000000000000/-696110440.xml contains a path separator . So we cannot create preferences on sdcard in our own folder structure . Am I right ?

Comment: ya its not possible preference is an xml what is the use of preference if its saving in the sd card.Its not possible you are right.You can just save the file and folders to the sdcard and not the preference.

Comment: Is it possible to delete folder1/folder2 when I uninstall my android app which was created using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ? If it is possible , please tell me how ?

Comment: You cant delete the folders created by your application when uninstalling the app but its possible to delete all the files inside the folder.

Comment: Please tell me how to delete all the files while unsinstalling app ? we need to listen for any uninstall intent ?